# jQuery Ajax load data from database but doesn't display it

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two files. One PHP-file, which contains a SQL-Select statement and returns the output as html. The second file is my index file which contains a div with the class "loadMembers" and some jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function startInterval() {
        var refreshId = setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'sidebars/members.php',
                type: 'html',
                success: function (resp) {
                    $("div.loadMembers").html(resp);
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
    startInterval();
});
```

I want to refresh the div with database data in a 5 seconds interval. I tried it also with .load()...

The request contains some data but nothing from my database...

Where's the problem?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I don't know why your code isn't working, but I do know that you want to use `setTimeout`, unless you want to do the update once after 5 seconds, twice after 10, three times after 15, etc...

Comment: The php-file works. I include it while loading the page.

Comment: Can you give an example of the response html, your problem could be there.

Answer (score 0):

your request type can be get or post, not `html`, it should be `dataType`

```
url : 'sidebars/members.php',
type: 'POST', // or GET
dataType : 'html',
```

Comment: True (bar the syntax errors in your code) but I don't think this will break the call, will it?

Comment: @lonesomeday That depends on the server. Since `html` isn't a standard http verb the webserver very well could reject the request.

Comment: @KevinB AIUI, browsers will translate unsupported verbs into ones they do support. I may be wrong, but certainly `DELETE` works like that on browsers that don't recognise it.

Comment: @lonesomeday A wiki is by no means an end-all source, however based on what's here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol i wouldn't expect the browser to change it. I could be wrong of course.